# PointCloud2 parse to xyz array in ROS2 with python

Tags: python, ros2, point-cloud

In ROS1 you can convert a pointCloud2 message to an xyz array with `sensor_msgs.point_cloud2.read_points()`.

Unfortunately, this option has not yet been adapted for ROS2.

What other options are there to obtain this.

Comment: What do you mean it hasn't been adapted for ROS2? [Here's a link to the `read_points` method in the ROS2 Github project](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs_py/sensor_msgs_py/point_cloud2.py#L61). Is there something not working about this?

Comment: Thank you Chuck. You made my day. Sorry I'm maybe not experienced enough to find the right links. I included in my installation and it works perfect. I use ROS via the official docker. It looks like these things are not pre-installed. Do you know why?

Comment: Happy to help, not sure what the official docker is though, or why it wouldn't have been included.